# trying to figure out how to pass the new input to 'playing' so that the while loop can read a fresh value

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to my computer game!")
print ("Would you like to play my computer knowledge game ?..")
playing = input("waiting... ")

if playing.lower().strip() == "no":
    quit()

if playing.lower().strip() == "yes":
    print("Okay, lets play !..")

while playing.lower().strip() != "yes" or "no":
    playing_2 = input("Would you like to play the Squid game?!... ")
    playing_2 = playing
```

Comment: That's not how you compare to two strings. Use `not in ('yes', 'no')`

Comment: Did you mean `playing = playing_2`?

Comment: Why do you need `playing_2`? Just assign to `playing` again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the very correct comments above. Instead:

```
print("Welcome to my computer game!")
print ("Would you like to play my computer knowledge game ?..")
playing = input("waiting... ")

if playing.lower().strip() == "no":
    quit()

if playing.lower().strip() == "yes":
    print("Okay, lets play !..")

while playing.lower().strip() in ("yes","no"):
    playing = input("Would you like to play the Squid game?!... ")
```

That `while` loop will ask the user over and over again if they wish to play the squid game and as long as they answer either "yes" or "no" it will continue asking them.

The two big changes here are:

1. To test if the user has inputted either "yes" or "no" we use the `in` operator in the `While` loops condition.
2. We set the `player` variable to the input from the user since `player` is what is being tested in the `While` loop's condition.

---

Making some assumptions about where you are headed, you may actually just want a single loop for the entirety of your program:

```
print("Welcome to my computer game!")  


while playing.lower().strip() == "yes":
    playing = input("Would you like to play the Squid game?!... ")
    ...rest of your game code here...
```

Once your game code/logic completes the while loop will iterate and ask them once again if they want to play the squid game. If they say anything besides "yes" it will exit the while loop and the program will end.

This is pretty common for games to have a main while loop in which the game runs. You may want to check out [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/about) and its nice framework and plethora of tutorials.

Comment: Thanks man.. THE suggestions helped.. Used not in ('yes', 'no') in the while loop and it worked just fine.. That's for the help..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers here useful I just need to get my while loop comparisons correctly and it worked. thanks, everyone

```
print("Welcome to my computer game!")
print("Would you like to play my computer knowledge game ?..")
playing = input('please answer yes or no....! ').lower().strip()
if playing == "no":
    quit()
if playing == "yes":
    print("okay lets play!...")
while playing not in ('yes', 'no'):
    playing = input('please answer yes or no....! ').lower().strip()
    if playing == "no":
        print('Thanks for your time, see you next time..')
        quit()
        break
    if playing == "yes":
        print("okay lets play!...")
        break
    else:
        continue
```